# How to access the store in React components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working off the react-redux example here: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise-sample

The redux store is being created in `setup.js` like so: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise-sample/blob/master/client/src/app/setup.js

key part:

```
const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {
  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      cats: [],
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer()
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

Outside of this file in a react component:
`CatsPage.js`

I'm trying to .dispatch(loadCats()) so the react app will fetch the list of cats from the server, update the store, and react magically update the dom. Here is what I have in CatsPage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CatList from './CatList';
import {loadCats} from '../../actions/catActions';
import {initStore} from '../../app/setup';

class CatsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rehydrated: false
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    initStore.dispatch(loadCats())
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cats</h1>
        <div>
          <CatList cats={this.props.cats} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CatsPage.propTypes = {
  cats: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    cats: state.cats
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CatsPage);
```

I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: _setup.initStore.dispatch is not a function`

I'm a react-redux beginner.

### Update

**CatList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const CatList = ({cats}) => {
  return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {cats.map(cat =>
           <li className="list-group-item" key={cat.id}>
            <Link to={'/cats/' + cat.id}>{cat.name}</Link>
           </li>
        )}
      </ul>
  );
};

CatList.propTypes = {
  cats: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default CatList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have setup your Provider correctly. If so correct way to access dispatch method is props. So you can do something like this.

```
this.props.dispatch(loadCats())
```

Comment: nice! that worked in that it made the call to the server and got the results... The results do not appear to be reflected in the DOM... The DOM is not updating. What would be the best way to debug why? Thanks

Comment: Your `cats` prop is hard coded. Did you change this line `cats: [{id:1, name: "Maru"}]` in your `mapStateToProps` and uncomment above line?

Comment: good point, if I change that to `cats: state.cats` I get the error CatList.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: is the updated mapStateToProps correct? It's now `cats: state.cats`

Comment: I'm using .map later in CatList.js, I just updated the question with the file... Ideas? Thanks